# Getting console error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

This is my code in the service.ts file

```
  private isMessageShown = new BehaviorSubject({ visibility: false});

  showMessage() {
    const visibilityDetails = {
      show: true,
    };
   this.isMessageShown.next(visibilityDetails);
   setTimeout(this.hideMessage.bind(this), 3000);
 }
 
 hideMessage() {
   this.isMessageShown.next({ visibility: false});
 }

 get messageVisibilityInfo() {
   return this.isMessageShown.asObservable();
 }
```

My service.spec.ts code related to showMessage assertion

```
  it('should get message status', done => {
    const result = service.messageVisibilityInfo;
    service.showMessage();
    result.subscribe(res => {
      expect(res.visibility).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
```

The test case is working fine as expected but I am having this error in the console

```
Uncaught Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
```

I have been trying to solve this error for a few days, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are implementing a service then you must have a UI component associated with it so that it render toast(i hope). Try removing the the timer and implement it such way

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toastObservable.currentToastVisibility.subscribe((data) => {
      // Do what every logic or work you want
      if (data.visibility) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.toastObservable.hideToast();
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
  }

--spec.ts
  it('should call ngOnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    spyOn(toaster, 'hideToast');
    tick(3000);
    expect(toaster.hideToast).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

i Had the same issue here, it turn out that I had a test with setTimeout.

so.. clear `setTimeOut()` and it will run

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dako pate but I don't have any unit test with `setTimeOut()`. Could you provide more detailed explanation

Comment: hello okay i got it ! so can i take a look to the project. ? i need to check or it's batter if you put this code live plateform like stackbliz..or other

Comment: I am sorry I cannot show you more code. But I think whatever is there is more than enough for analysis.